# Printing in Chrome without a confirmation window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

I found an article which explains [how to bypass the printer dialog box](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/05/09/javascript-print-bypass-printer-dialog-in-ie-and-firefox/) in FireFox and IE.

Is there a way to achieve this in Chrome as well?

Comment: In the JavaScript run time of web sites, or via browser settings the user has to set as both the IE and FF example requires?

Comment: That link provides end-user guidance on turning this off, so I'm guessing that this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @August - I'm assuming that this is possible only if the user changed some specific settings. Of course, there could be more to that after he did.

Comment: @Marcelo - the IE example contains a bit more than the user settings changes. Maybe there is more to it in the Chrome solution as well (if there is one).

Comment: @Kuzco: Perhaps, but frankly it is a terrible idea to try to implement a feature that requires that users change their browser settings. It reminds me of the early days of the web, when many misguided designers presented instructions on how to change screen dimensions, default fonts and colors in order for their site to display properly. In this case it's more of an anti-feature, since bypassing the printer dialog will result in many print jobs being sent with the wrong settings, or to the wrong printer, etc.

Comment: @Marcelo - when it comes to a public website, I agree this could be a bad idea. But when a specific client has a specific need for such a feature, I don't think there is much harm in it.

Comment: @Kuzco: The question of whether there is harm in it is quite orthogonal to whether the client asked for it or not. Clients frequently ask for things that are not in their best interests. In this case, you would be risking of all kinds of printing accidents for the sake of sparing users a single keystroke (the enter key).

Comment: @Marcelo - it is not about sparing keystrokes from users, it is about printing automatically in some cases.

Comment: @Kuzco: Since you can automatically bring up the print dialog with a simple `window.print()`, what purpose is there to your question, other than to avoid the need to press [Enter]?

Comment: @Marcelo - by automatically I meant without any user touch. So there isn't necessarily anyone there to press [Enter].

Comment: @Kuzco: You want a browser window to kick off a print job automatically with no one present? What kind of setup is this?

Comment: It's a situation where upon certain events an order or a receipt needs to be printed and passed to an employee who might not be near a computer. Ideally this wouldn't happen via a browser window, but since a web application is already up this is the quickest solution at the moment.